# New to Visual Studio Code - my program isn't compiling

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a folder called foo and within that folder I have a very simple html file that should output some basic code. I don't know how to run this.

Every time I try running and compiling the html file, I get the error

> "Could not find the preLaunchTask 'exe'."

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Extension",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": [
            "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "exe"
    }
]
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Is `exe` a valid `preLaunchTask`?